# My MongoDB authentication config is not working

Tags: mongodb, macos, authentication, homebrew

I installed MongoDB using homebrew on my mac. 
And I created admin account on my local mongodb. 
Then, I added below code to my 'mongod.conf' to use authentication mode. 
The code is 'security: authorization: enabled'.

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

And I restarted MongoDB. 'brew services restart mongodb'
But whenever I start mongo shell, it still print

```
WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
```

And naturally it can be used without user connection.
How can I resolve this problem?
If I type

```
db.auth("username", "password")
```

It print '1'. <- authenticated.
Is it impossible to authenticate mongoDB if I use homebrew?
I don't know what I have to do anymore.
Please, Help me.
Thank you.


+ It's full log

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("573560e4-0a3a-472e-a94a-79b1cecab4fd") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.3
Server has startup warnings: 
2019-08-27T19:02:40.847+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-08-27T19:02:40.847+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-08-27T19:02:40.847+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-08-27T19:02:40.847+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you have specified the Authentication Mechanism in config file. Please add it to your mongod config file

```
security:
  authorization: enabled

setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Once the above is done, restart your mongo instance and that should work

Comment: I followed your method above.
It is not working...
I attached my configure file(mongod.conf).
Please check the file.
Thank Anban for your quick response.

Comment: systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: Do you get any error any error? Can you also check what is being logged in your mongod log file and post it here?

Comment: I’m not sure why it’s not reading the authentication mechanism. Can you try to restart your service using the command specified in the below link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.authenticationMechanisms

Comment: Finally, I gave up trying to start server using homebrew.
Still I don't know reason why my configuration doesn't working.
Anyway...

'brew services start mongodb' (x) -> 'mongod --auth' (o)

Now, it works.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

1. try removing the current service
2. enable authorization first in the config file and then run mongod daemon for the very first time.
3. mongo allows "localhost exception". Read about it in the documentation
4. then create first account with required privileges on the admin database. Make sure to include privileges of creating other users.
5. restart mongod daemon.

check if error goes away..

point is to enable authorization before creating any user, even before admin.